# List View Threshold - Error

Tags: list-view-threshold, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have a custom aspx page used by Owners group (Full Control) that displays files that are checked out and files that have been uploaded but never checked in. We also have more than a few libraries with over 2500-4000 files each. We hit a List View Threshold error in the past but that was solved by running the functions on the custom application page with Elevated Privileges. Our Web Application's List View Threshold is set to 5K and our List View Threshold for Auditors and Admninistrators is set to 50K. My question is, with the functions ran with Elevated Privileges, what is the List View Threshold for the Owners group? Is it 50K? If not what is the LVT before the Owners group gets a threshold error? I just need some clarification on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RunWithElevatedPreviliges` causes the code to run using app pool account and this account has administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool. Hence in your case Owners will have the same LVT as administrators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that cleared up some suspicion of mine!

Answer (score 0):

1. List View Threshold for Auditors and Administrators is 20K by default
   [Resource throttles and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-11ecc804-2284-4978-8273-4842471fafb7#__toc264017709)
2. By Administrators it means Site Collection Administrators, so Owners aren't implicitly included